# Swift - A little confusion between Required Initializer vs. Delegating initializer

Tags: swift, polymorphism

I am having a bit of confusion between required and delegating initializers when it comes to Swift classes.

As you can see below in my example code, NewDog can be initialized in 1 of 2 ways. As you can see, you can initialize by supplying just the age upon initialization, in which case, a default name will be assigned ("Buddy").

What I don't understand yet is why the NewDog class needs the required keyword for an initializer, if that initializer is not even being used?? See.. var georgie is using the regular initializer (not the required one in NewDog) and it works just fine.

So what is the point of it being required if it is... in fact.. NOT required? *If I take away that initializer the compiler yells at me saying "required' initializer 'init' must be provided by subclass of 'Dog'".

Well okay... I put it back in.. but yet I don't have to even use it, because the first initializer in NewDog is fulfilling all of the member property initializations... I do not see the logic here.

```
class Dog {
    var name : String
    required init(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class NewDog: Dog {
    var age : Int?
    init(age: Int, name: String) {
        super.init(name)
        self.age = age
    }

    required init(_ name: String) {
        super.init(name)
    }
}

var georgie = NewDog(age: 6, name: "Georgie")
georgie.age
```

So can someone explain to me what the required keyword is for? My guess it that it is just to tell the compiler "hey... calm down... the name property WILL be initialized in our subclass because you are yelling at me to require it... so just chill out and I will handle it on my own. I'm going to do it in an explicit subclass initializer that I am creating myself"...

*****ALSO! Bonus question: Which one of the initializers in NewDog is the Designated Initializer??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `required` initializer means that every subclass must also implement the same initializer. Since you made the `init(_:)` initializer required in the `Dog` class, every subclass (and their subclasses) of `Dog` must also provide the same `required init(_:)` initializer.

From the looks of things, you don't need to make the `init(_:)` initializer in the `Dog` class required. Remove that keyword and then you can remove the `init(_:)` initializer from the `NewDog` class.

Bonus - both `init` methods in your `NewDog` class are designated initializers since neither is a convenience initializer.

You need to learn the differences and uses of default, convenience, and required initializers. This is all clearly covered in the [Intializers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203) section of [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH3-ID0) book.

Comment: I was only confused on the differences between designated and required. Thanks though. Also, the required init in the Dog class was for polymorphemic purposes. Made a factory that takes a Dog type and initializes and returns a new instance. Since it took a Dog type, required was necessary to let the compiler know that I may be passing through a subclass of the Dog type, so that it doesn't freak out on me.

Comment: So, true or false... Required, in your words, means that "every subclass must also implement the same initializer", however... that does NOT mean that the subclass has to USE that initializer. As made obvious by my example above, the instance was created with a different designated initializer.

Comment: True, `required` means it must exist. It doesn't mean it must be used.

Comment: ...As long as the property/properties that the required initializer is attempting to initialize is/are being covered by a different delegating initializer. Correct? Like in my example how the init(age:name:) initializer is doing that. Hm that's interesting because that means the compiler is smart enough to know that, in a polymorphic sense, I can now use NewDog anywhere it expects a Dog, because it knows that I have at least covered the required 'name' property being initialized...